# Disable Telerik radgrid EditMode

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

I listen to the EditCommand-event of my radgrid and open my own popup to let the user edit the dataset selected. But the radgrid opens his own edit form everytime too. Is there a way to disable the radgrids edit form completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this problem by myself. My column which contains the LinkButton to open the edit popup is defined like this:

```
GridColumn gbcEdit = defineGridButtonColumn("[image_url]", "Edit", "editRow");
```

Then I register an event to the radgrid.ItemCommand:

```
this.radgrid.ItemCommand += radgrid_ItemCommand;
```

In this event I check whether the command is "editRow" or not. Notice that if you write only "edit" as the command, the radgrid will open its own edit mode template everytime.

```
private void radgrid_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.CommandName == "editRow")
          //Show own edit popup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User RadGrid_Prerender:- PreRender is called before the control is rendered for the page.

ASPX:-

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

    foreach( GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items ) 
    { 
        LinkButton btnEdit = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("columnEdit"); 
        btnEdit.Enabled = false; 
    } 

}
```

Hope Its Work !!

Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thank your for your quick answer. Unfortunately that wasn't the solution for what i tried to describe. I tried a few other things and finally found a solution by myself (see answer below).

Comment: @Simboryo, I think that you question was unclear as your 1rst statement was "I listen to the EditCommand-event ". I have read this sentece as your answer code. As this is the only way to listen to edit command. If you were listening the wrong event how could he knew? You should read [ask] and [mcve] for your next question. you will have better answer this way.

Comment: I don't see an error in my question. I specified that i open my own popup but the radgrid opens his too. I thought I did something wrong in the event because i didn't know better.